# mathJax on iphone with device width yields image fonts

Tags: javascript, iphone, mathjax

I'm using MathJax to render math symbols on a page designed for viewing on a mobile device, say an iphone.  When I use the meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
```

this causes a problem somehow.  The MathJax doesn't load web fonts and instead it falls back on image fonts, which are inferior.  This problem vanishes if I explicitly set a width in pixels that is greater than a certain cut-off.  If I set

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=360px" />
```

for example, it loads web fonts without a problem.  So I wonder...is there an elegant solution to this?  I'd prefer not to use an absolute width, but a page rendered with web-fonts is a somewhat higher priority in my book.

Here's an example of a page that fails in this respect:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://d3eoax9i5htok0.cloudfront.net/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-   AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span style="color:green">
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is issue is resolved in version 2.0 of MathJax.  The beta version is available at http://devel.mathjax.org/mathjax/dpvc/v2.0-candidate/MathJax.js so could you try that out and see if that works better for you?

See also the [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mathjax-users/O4CqhYye5tk) on the MathJax user's forum.  A suggested work-around is

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
 MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("HTML-CSS Jax Ready", function () {
   var HTMLCSS = MathJax.OutputJax["HTML-CSS"];
   HTMLCSS.Font.testSize = ["10px","12px","15px","9px","8px"];
   document.getElementById("MathJax_Font_Test").style.fontSize = "10px";
 });
 </script>
```

which changes the font sizes to use when detecting the web fonts.